# The text in my paragraph tags isn't vertically aligned like it should be

Tags: html, css

I used the `line-height` property so that the inner text of my div would be vertically aligned:

```
div.header
{
    background-color: #00325f;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width: 880px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Hence, the `00011101010000110101010` from the following should be in the middle of the div in which it resides.

```
<div class="header">
     <p>00011101010000110101010</p>
</div>
```

But when I preview my page, it's up at the top of the div like usual. Can someone help me resolve this issue and explain the HTML logic behind the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your `line-height` should be `50px` not `25px` to vertically center the text.

```
div.header
{
    background-color: #00325f;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width: 880px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

The `line-height` should be the same height as the container itself.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7eZGe/